# How to share on whatsapp without opening UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I want to open whatsapp directly to share video .

Now its open `UIActivityViewController` and then I have to select whatsapp
and I dont want this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it work

```
NSString *str = @"http://r.yoz.io/PJ.c.d?";//video url

str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@id=%@",str];
str = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CFStringRef originalURLString = (__bridge CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
CFStringRef preprocessedURLString = CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, originalURLString, CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
NSString *urlString = (__bridge NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, preprocessedURLString, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
NSString *whatsAppURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@", urlString];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:whatsAppURLString]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:whatsAppURLString]];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [warningAlert show];
}
```